# VSDBCMD remotely

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vsdbcmd, db-schema

Can I run the VSDBCMD command remotely? I mean without copying the files to the SQL server? I am trying to create a dbschema file to use it as a reference in a database project.

I tried to run the command on my machine, and I get the following error: "TSD An error was received from SQL Server while attempting to reverse engineer elements of type Microsoft.Data.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.ISql100DatabaseEncryptionKey: The user does not have permission to perform this action. An unexpected failure occurred: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Pivotal_dev_ed.dbschema' is denied."

Do I need special permission on the SQl server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, it seems you can run it remotely, you just have to specify the path to the folder where you want the schema to be saved. I got the error mentioned above because I didn't had permissions to write on the server, but specifying a path to a folder where I could write solved the problem